# share a private github account with everyone in a organization

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to easily share a private repository on github with everyone in an organization?

If I clone the repository under the organization does it count as one of the private repositories for the organization?

Comment: Is this a technical or a legal question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I've understood you correctly.

If you fork a private repository (and you belong to an organisation) you should be offered the choice of which organisation you'd like the forked repository to live under.

[I don't think this forked repository counts](https://github.com/pricing) as a new private repository for your organisation.